# How to change modeline color with active minibuffer and switch to other-window

Tags: emacs, elisp

Within the same frame *and* with an active minibuffer, can anyone think of a way to have switch to `other-window` behave similar to a `minibuffer-exit-hook` (*without* completely exiting the minibuffer)?

Essentially, I'd like to have the main windows show an inactive modeline color when focus is in the minibuffer, and then update the modline to active (for a window that has focus) when I move from the semi-active minibuffer to another window using `other-window`.

For example, there are two windows open in the same frame (side by side) -- Window # 1 are my notes -- Window # 2 is a Big Brother Database display of a record that I want to modify.  So I open the minibuffer to input my record modification and then switch back and forth between my notes in Window # 1 and the minibuffer to copy and paste the relevant portions.  When using `other-window` to jump between the three areas, it is still difficult to know whether focus is in the minibuffer or another window.

```
Window # 1 (notes)         |     Window # 2 (bbdb record display)
                           |
___________________________|_____________________________________
Name:  lawlist . . .
```

---

```lisp
(defun enter-minibuffer-setup ()
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
    :height 160 :foreground "gray70" :background "black")
(set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
    '((default :background "gray10" :foreground "yellow"))))

(defun exit-minibuffer-setup ()
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
    :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "gray70"))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'enter-minibuffer-setup)

(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook  'exit-minibuffer-setup)
```

Comment: What is the question? Doesn't your code do what you want?

Comment: When the minibuffer is active, the modeline status of both windows goes inactive.  When I use `other-window` without closing the minibuffer (e.g., when I need to copy the name or address from Window # 1 and then switch back to the minibuffer to paste), the only indication is `a blinking cursor` to indicate a change of focus.  I was hoping to have the modeline also change when using `other-window` to switch between the minibuffer and Window # 1 or 2.

Comment: I see. Dunno the answer, unless there will be a buffer-switching hook at some point. There was, however, some discussion in the thread of [bug #155767](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15577#53) about this, and whether the major-mode change when entering/exiting the minibuffer triggers mode-change hooks etc.

Comment: Is it possible to use the availability of a `keymap` in lieu of a major or minor mode to specify the existence or non-existence of condition -- e.g., when `minibuffer-local-map` is active, then set mode-line to red, otherwise blue?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But you can also just check the value of `major-mode`. `(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (message "Major mode: %s" major-mode) (sleep-for 1))`. Or you can check the value of `(current-buffer)`. The problem is not to be able to check whether the minibuffer is the current buffer or window or mode, but to find the right trigger: to act upon some event or change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to "[advise](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html)" the `other-window` function to execute some form when switching to the minibuffer.

For example, the following code will turn the minibuffer prompt green when you cycle back to it using `other-window`, and if you land on a non minibuffer window it turns the prompt grey:

```
(defadvice other-window (after adv-other-window-minibuffer
                               (COUNT &optional ALL-FRAMES))
  "Make minibuffer prompt green when switched to"
  (if (minibufferp)
      (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
                          :foreground "green" :background "black")
    (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
                          :foreground "dark grey" :background "black")))

(ad-activate 'other-window)
```

Of course you are not limited to just setting the minibuffer prompt, but it's not clear to me exactly what effect your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed advice -- I'll give it a whirl.  I just tried substituting `(minibufferp)` for `(equal (buffer-name) " *Minibuf-1*")` in my first working draft answer, and it works well.  I had never seen `(minibufferp)` used before -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updated draft -- borrowing `(minibufferp)` from @Carl Groner

```
(defun enter-minibuffer-setup ()
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
    :height 160 :foreground "gray70" :background "black")
  (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
    '((default :background "black" :foreground "yellow")))
  (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
    :background "black" :foreground "cyan"))

(defun exit-minibuffer-setup ()
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
    :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "gray70")
  (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
    :background "black" :foreground "cyan"))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'enter-minibuffer-setup)

(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 'exit-minibuffer-setup)

(defun lawlist-minibuffer-conditions ()
  (cond
    ((minibufferp)
      (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
        :height 160 :foreground "gray70" :background "black")
      (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
        :background "black" :foreground "cyan"))
    (t
      (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
        :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "gray70")
      (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil
        :background "black" :foreground "gray70")) ))

(defun lawlist-forward-window ()
(interactive)
  (other-window 1)
  (lawlist-minibuffer-conditions))

(defun lawlist-backward-window ()
(interactive)
  (other-window -1)
  (lawlist-minibuffer-conditions))
```